# Does rails 3.2.1 have the has_secure_password method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know if rails 3.2.1 has the method `has_secure_password`?

Where can I go to find this out? Google gives me generic links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.1/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L34

In the future, you can use api.rubyonrails.org to find the method. Then click "Show on Github". Then select the tag you want from the Github tag menu for Rails.